# How to scrape all p-tag and corresponding h2-tag with selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I want to get `title` and `content` of article:

```
<h2><span>Title1</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<h2><span>Title2</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<h2><span>Title3</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
```

and sesult expectect is

```
title=[title1, title2, title3]
content = [content1,content2,content3]
```

and append all p string to content1,and append all p string to content2,and append all p string to content3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach could be to work with a `dict` that keys are based on your `<h2>`, update their values while iterating the `<p>` by its `preceding-sibling::h2[1]`:

```
data = dict((e.text,'') for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h2'))

for p in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'p'):
    data[p.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text] = data[p.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text]+' '+p.text

print(data)
-> {'Title1': ' text I want text I want', 'Title2': ' text I want text I want text I want', 'Title3': ' text I want text I want'}
```

Now you could simply assign your variables by using `.keys()` and `.values()`:

```
title = list(data) ### or title = list(data.keys())
-> ['Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3']

content = list(data.values())
-> [' text I want text I want', ' text I want text I want text I want', ' text I want text I want']
```

But would recommend to stay more structured and working with the `dict` itself or a list of dicts:

```
[{'title':x,'content':y} for x,y in data.items()]
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

html = '''
<h2><span>Title1</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<h2><span>Title2</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
<h2><span>Title3</span></h2>
<p>text I want</p>
<p>text I want</p>
'''

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

data = dict((e.text,'') for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'h2'))
for p in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'p'):
    data[p.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text] = data[p.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text]+' '+p.text

[{'title':x,'content':y} for x,y in data.items()]
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'Title1', 'content': ' text I want text I want'},
 {'title': 'Title2', 'content': ' text I want text I want text I want'},
 {'title': 'Title3', 'content': ' text I want text I want'}]
```

Comment: thanks @HedgeHog for your help, i have try this on page https://facts.net/best-survival-movies/ and have problem, its html similar (h2 and p) with my example, but not work. Can you help me.

Comment: Sure, but in my opinion this would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus. Simply link it here in the comments.

Comment: yes, i have just create new ask in link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73521281/how-to-scrape-all-p-tag-and-corresponding-h2-tag-with-selenium-example-web