# How to scrape all p-tag and its corresponding h2-tag with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I want to get `title` and `content` of article: example web :https://facts.net/best-survival-movies/
I want to append all `p` in `h2[tcontent-title]`

[image]

and the result expected is:

```
title=[title1, title2, title3]

content = [content1,content2,content3]
```

and append all p string to content1,and append all p string to content2,and append all p string to content3
can you help me.

Comment: Would be great to take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from your last question is not working, cause there are some `<p>` that are not siblings in the structure, they are nested in an `<aside>` and the `preceding-sibling` will fail.

You could switch to `preceding` only, but this will grab also the `<p>` from the `<aside>` - To fix this, simply select the elements more specific:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.single-title-desc-wrap p:not(aside>p)')
```

##### Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://facts.net/best-survival-movies/')
data = dict((e.text,'') for e in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.single-title-desc-wrap h2'))
for p in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.single-title-desc-wrap p:not(aside>p)'):
    data[p.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text] = data[p.find_element(By.XPATH, './preceding-sibling::h2[1]').text]+' '+p.text

[{'title':x,'content':y} for x,y in data.items()]
```

Comment: Greate! its worked.Thanks you very much.Actually, I just learned about select CSS, XPATH and am very confused in some of your commands. Especially in terms of search structure. I will learn more about this, thanks you @HedgeHog